# Best way to implement trial period or expire time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to show off some of my work, but i don't want it to be kept forever.

I've tried this trial period that checks on launch if date has past.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def check_trial():
        trial_start = "2019-09-03"
        trial_end = datetime.strptime(trial_start, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=5)
        today = datetime.now()

    if today > trial_end:
        print("Trial Expired")
        os._exit()


def main():
    print("running")


check_trial()
main()
```

Im scared if they just change their computer date then this wont run. What should be done to protect against that?

Comment: If they have the source code, they don't even need to change their computer's date; they'll just edit the code.

Comment: There's probably nothing you can do, short of requiring some sort of tamper-resistant physical device (aka a "dongle") to be present and plugged into the computer — an approach with a number of its own downsides…

Comment: Not related to the problem but you should use `sys.exit()` instead of `exit()`, as the latter is only meant to be used in an interactive Python shell.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this completes your requirement but here is an alternate method using `signal` module in python. Let us suppose that `run()` function runs your application and you want it to run for 10 mins.

```
import signal

signal.alarm(600)
run()
signal.alarm(0)
```

This will simply run your `run()` function till 600 seconds and if the function doesn't stop execution it will forcefully break the execution of the function.